# Count values in each column of R dataframe based on which range they're in

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a 1246 x 60,660 dataframe in R. A snippet of the data:

```
                     gene1             gene2              gene3
sample1          1615.7529         41.932474           697.9728
sample2           663.2001          8.602831          1198.1398
sample3          2406.1532         12.622443          1033.4625
sample4           836.3808         60.144235           259.3720
sample5          1217.8192         22.775497           695.9924
sample6           865.0344         15.350298           683.5397
sample7           935.3658         20.380676           540.6242
sample8           667.3883         56.939874          1056.6981
```

For each gene, I want each sample's value to be put into one of the following groups:

none = 0

ultra low = 1-4

low = 5 - 100

medium = 101 - 1000

high = 1000 & up

The end product would be another matrix/dataframe looking something like this:

```
                  gene1      gene2      gene3
none                  0          0          0 
ultra low             0          0          0
low                   0          8          0
medium                5          0          5
high                  3          0          3
```

How could I do this? After a bit of searching I think I'd probably end up using `count` or maybe `aggregate`? But I'm not sure exactly how to apply it to each column. Most of the examples I've seen were counting only one column.

Comment: `case_when` from package dplyr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be easier with `cut` - i.e. specify the `breaks` and the corresponding `labels` in each of the columns by looping with `lapply` and get the frequency count with `table`

```
sapply(df1, \(x) table(cut(x, breaks = c(0, 1, 5, 101, 1001, Inf), 
   labels = c("none", "ultra low", "low", "medium", "high"))))
```

-output

```
           gene1 gene2 gene3
none          0     0     0
ultra low     0     0     0
low           0     8     0
medium        5     0     5
high          3     0     3
```

Or as @ZheyuanLi mentioned, `tabulate` could be faster

```
lbls <- c("none", "ultra low", "low", "medium", "high")
out <- sapply(df1, \(x) tabulate(cut(x, breaks = c(0, 1, 5, 101, 1001, Inf), 
   labels = lbls), nbins = length(lbls)))
row.names(out) <- lbls
```

-output

```
> out
          gene1 gene2 gene3
none          0     0     0
ultra low     0     0     0
low           0     8     0
medium        5     0     5
high          3     0     3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(gene1 = c(1615.7529, 663.2001, 2406.1532, 836.3808, 
1217.8192, 865.0344, 935.3658, 667.3883), gene2 = c(41.932474, 
8.602831, 12.622443, 60.144235, 22.775497, 15.350298, 20.380676, 
56.939874), gene3 = c(697.9728, 1198.1398, 1033.4625, 259.372, 
695.9924, 683.5397, 540.6242, 1056.6981)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("sample1", 
"sample2", "sample3", "sample4", "sample5", "sample6", "sample7", 
"sample8"))
```

Comment: The version with ```tabulate``` worked great! Quick question: I was wondering what the backslash before (x) does. Is it telling ```sapply``` what function to apply to the dataframe?

Comment: @mfeldbauer it is a lambda function concise option (`function(x)` would be `\(x)` in the newer R versions).  So, if you are using an older R version, change it to `function(x)` to make it work

Comment: Gotcha! It worked with ```\(x)``` but I had never seen that formatting before. Good to know, thank you!